# Custom Product Fields in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

To make adding products easy on a site for an end user they want  to fill out custom text fields such as brand, size, etc.

I would imagine the field data can show below short description on front end.

I have found a couple of articles several years old however their coding doesn't apply anymore and causing several errors.  I have a child theme and only want to edit the child theme.

Can someone help provide coding for this to display the custom text fields on the add product page and then display them on the front end of the product page?

Comment: Are you using Advanced Custom Fields? If you are you can make a field group for your products with the custom fields then edit your themes template files to call the_field()

Comment: Research around action hooks "woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data" for adding custom fields in product form (in back end) and "woocommerce_process_product_meta" for saving those fields. Corresponding to your field names you can retrieve that data to display in front end.

Comment: It appears that I can use Advanced Custom Fields and another plugin called ACF for Woocommerce Products to achieve this.

Two Problems with this:
1. The items are labeled on a single line in the short description.  It would be nice to have them on their own line.
2. Not all products will have input.  If these fields are left empty the empty Field Name is displayed for all products.  

Getting Closer!